# Duda sobre código de ordenación de números en arrays

Tags: array, c, bucle-for, ordenamiento

Tengo un código que pide 4 números por teclado, los mete en un array, los muestra y luego los ordena de menor a mayor mediante un algoritmo de inserción. Quiero que todo se trabaje en variables double. Si declaro el array como int me ordena los números de menor a mayor (lo que quiero). El problema es que si con exactamente EL MÍSMO CÓDIGO cambio el int por double y todos los %i por %d me ordena los números de mayor a menor (???) No entiendo absolutamente nada, no se por qué puede pasar tal cosa. Por si las dudas he hecho el bucle que ordena los números en papel 3 veces y efectivamente los ordena de menor a mayor. Os dejo el código por aqui a ver si me podeis echar una mano :) (obviad el tamaño del array)

```
double orden[100];
double temporal = 0;
int i = 0, j = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                printf("Introduce un número para la posición %i:\n", i);
                scanf("%d", &orden[i]);
            }
            printf("Los números a ordenar son: ");
            for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                printf("%d, ", orden[i]);
            }
            printf("\n");
            for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
                j = i - 1;
                temporal = orden[i];
                while (orden[j] > temporal && j >= 0) {
                    orden[j + 1] = orden[j];
                    j--;
                }
                orden[j + 1] = temporal;
            }
            printf("La serie de números ordenados quedaría: ");
            for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                printf("%d, ", orden[i]);
            }
```

Comment: ***%i por %d***. Ese cambio no hace nada. `%d` sigue [leyendo un entero](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/)

Comment: vale perdonad mi estupidez, soy nuevo en esto de la programación. no me explico por que eso hacia que se me ordenasen los números al revés pero así era. he cambiado los %d por %lf y ahora me los ordena de menor a mayor. muchas gracias

Comment: Lo que sucede es que la forma en la que se colocan en la memoria los valores no es la misma para los diferentes tipos de variable. De hecho, creo que ni esta estandarizada, ya que cuando lo hago en mi maquina me salen numeros basura. Entonces lees para una distribucion de memoria, y ordenas los datos para otra. Es por eso. Mucha suerte aprendiendo, y aqui estamos cualquier cosa.